# creating new partition on windows and now have problem on GRUB and not booting

Tags: boot, grub2, mount

I have a Sony Vaio Laptop That has Original Windows 7. I installed a Linux inside a Windows.( I had a system with windows and a Linux) . I create a new partition on My Computer of Windows. but after restart system not booting and there is an this message on Screen  :

```
GNU GRUB version 0.97-71.fc15 ( 634k lower /3651056k upper memory Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported for the first word, TAB lists possible command completions Anywhere else TAB lists the possible completions of a device /filename.)
```

Now I can mount Windows file by use of live Ubuntu CD but can't mount my Linux partitions :(

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to me
1)you can use `Gparted` Application in live CD mode and get all device information.

2)Or use command "`fdisk -l`" and show all available Disk and its partition

3)or `blkid`

if still problem then update your grub file and make dual-boot mode.